# Dependency version differences in .NET / NuGET project

Tags: .net, nuget

Sorry if this question is completely lame - this is just all new to me and a bit confusing!

I pulled down the source for RavenDB from github here: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb

Now if I search all of that source for GeoAPI, this comes back (reformatted for readability):

```
Raven.Database/Raven.Database.csproj:    
    <Reference Include="GeoAPI, Version=1.6.4448.22541, Culture=neutral, 
               PublicKeyToken=a1a0da7def465678, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
Raven.Database/Raven.Database.csproj:      
    <HintPath>..\SharedLibs\GeoAPI.dll</HintPath>

Raven.Tests/Raven.Tests.csproj:    
    <Reference Include="GeoAPI, Version=1.7.4693.18483, Culture=neutral,   
               PublicKeyToken=a1a0da7def465678, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
Raven.Tests/Raven.Tests.csproj:      
    <HintPath>..\SharedLibs\GeoAPI.dll</HintPath>
```

So it looks like two .csproj files refer to the same GeoAPI.dll file, though one reference is to version 1.6.4448.22541 and one is to 1.7.4693.18483!

As I said, completely new to this (ok, a bit clueless!), but is this normal/ok?  What version would that DLL file be?  Also, I gave only the single example, but this version mismatch occurs again and again (at least within RavenDB).  FYI: there is only one GeoAPI.dll on the filesystem and that is the one referenced.

Thanks to anyone who can help explain!

Comment: This is perfect acceptable, I assume RavenDb is making use of a [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) to make this work. You can verify by looking in the config files